# $f(x)=1/\lfloor1/x\rfloor$; find $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Given the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{\lfloor1/x\rfloor}&0<x\le1\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$
Knowing it is integrable on $[0,1]$, and knowing the identity:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$
Find $\int_0^1f(x)\,dx$.

I know it probably has to do with Riemann sums but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\newcommand{\d}[1]{\; \mathrm{d} #1}
\newcommand{\f}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}
\newcommand{\bb}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
$$
You don't require Riemann sum. Observe that, if $\frac{1}{n+1} < x \leq \frac{1}{n}$, then $n \leq \frac{1}{x} < n + 1$, so $\f{\frac{1}{x}} = n$.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 f(x) \d{x} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\frac{1}{n+1}^\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\f{\frac{1}{x}}} \d{x} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\frac{1}{n+1}^\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{n} \d{x} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\bb{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}
\end{align*}
The sum on the left is given. Can you evaluate the sum on the right?

Comment: Can you explain the first equality? (The first line of the big chunk of text, idk how to copy it). I don't think  we studied that, though it makes sense. Perhaps you see a more basic solution with Riemann/Darboux?

Comment: $\newcommand{\d}[1]{\; \mathrm{d} #1}$
Recall the basic property that:
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \d{x} = \int_a^c f(x) \d{x} + \int_c^b f(x) \d{x}
$$
What I'm doing is basically this, but infinitely many times:
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \d{x} = \int_\frac{1}{2}^1 f(x) \d{x} + \int_\frac{1}{3}^\frac{1}{2} f(x) \d{x} + \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{3} f(x) \d{x} + \cdots
$$
The solution is as basic as it can get. If you're unsure on how to evaluate the second infinite sum, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1027110/infinite-series-sum-1-nn1).

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\frac1{n+1}}^{\frac1n}f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\frac1{n+1}}^{\frac1n}\frac1{n}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Using the fact that If
$$x\in [\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k-1}]$$
then
$$\frac 1x \in [k-1,k]$$
and
$$f(x) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{k-1}}$$
So

$$\int_0^1f=$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{\frac{1}{k}}^{\frac{1}{k-1}}f=$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac 1k)\color{red}{\frac{ 1}{k-1}}=$$

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac 1k)$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$